# vite react express bug for mobile

Tags: reactjs, express, mobile, render, vite

There is a bug with vite react, it doesn't render the data from the backend to the frontend in mobile, but calling the backend /ping or routes with res json the backend does respond.

```
github:https://github.com/dev-ronaaldll/try-mern-mysql-crud
```

Creating a basic crud of tasks, the backend data is not displayed with react on mobile.
What extra configuration do it need to make it work?
I have the solution but I want to know if someone can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 Solution
replace the fetch/axios from localhost to "ip/192.168.1.100" works.
2 Solution
using a proxy conf in vite and react